# Which correlation method to us?

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I am debating whether to use Pearson's correlation or Kendall's tau on a set of data. While linear relationships among subsets of the data are reasonable, I am deeply skeptical that they exist throughout the data, so I am reluctant to use Pearson's correlation. Also, while I've read on Research Gate that Kendall's tau is preferable to Spearman's rho for smaller data samples (like mine), I also read that it's used generally for ordinal data -- which brings me back to Pearson's metric.

Keeping in mind that the results from the "winning" method will be inputted into a copula that will be involved in a week-long simulation, I'd like to get it right the first time, and was hoping your advice could steer me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: similar question here, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/pearson-vs-spearman-vs-kendall

Comment: Thank you! Didn’t pop up when I was searching for an answer on Google. My challenge is that my data are not necessarily independent. For example: I have monthly hydro-generation data for weekdays from 7am to 10pm and for weekdays from 11pm through 7am. I would imagine that river flow at night is partly determined by river flow during the day and vice versa — but I need to keep the two separate, as the first set of generation during the first peak trades at different prices than that on the second peak. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

**Correlation coefficient** is **not robus**t enough to say there's a relationship or not, as it's somehow just care about a **small range** of relationships, such (**linear relationship**) in case of **Pearson's correlation coefficient**.

---

In **time-series** data, the correlation coefficient is useless as there's a complex relation (i.e. there's no linear nor ranking relationship), you could try **Arima model** instead.

Comment: Thing is, I need to somehow capture the relationship among variables, in order to generate my copulas. Is there an alternative to a correlation matrix of which I'm not aware?

Comment: There's a lot of ways you could go through, you could try statistical test with a time-shifting, you could try to compute the correlation coefficient for weighted average - compute weighted average, then shift data and split into k-groups, compute correlation coefficient for each group separately. (I guess it's a terrible approximation, but i believe it's quite good ), but  a statistical test is the best way, consider using **ADF Test** too.

Comment: In case of you really want use correlation directly, then I guess Spearman or Kendall's Tau, over k-subset of the data set (i.e. shift data, selection based window size), is the way to find least reasonable results. The idea behind data splitting, is trying to approximate data to (n-lines or monotonic function), then compute correlation coefficient.